# RailsInstaller issue with fresh Mountain Lion install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion, railsinstaller

I previously had Rails installed on OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion, but I just recently reformatted my hard drive and am in the process of setting up the computer again.

I've downloaded RailsInstaller as I believe that's how I installed Rails on 10.8 before, but right at the beginning of the install, right after entering my full name and email for git, I get an error.

It states `There has been an error. Error changing group of /opt/rix to rvm. The application will exit now.` and then exits. It gives me no solution to the problem with the error message, and I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and knows of a work around.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving the same error message.  After restarting my computer and trying the install again it worked just fine.  Go figure.

Comment: That's one of the first things I tried since I had just installed a bunch of updates for OS X and thought it might be causing an issue, but unfortunately that didn't fix it for me.

Comment: Was instructing an intro to rails course.  Several people faced this problem and restarting corrected it for all of them.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same problem and like Aaron said a restart might fix it. It did not for me so I did one other step and changed the preference for application downloads (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General) "Allow application downloads from:" to "Anywhere", restarted the computer and it installed just fine.

Comment: I ended up going with the way Leo said to do it, but next time I need to re-install rails I'll definitely test it this way before I go through the manual process. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A simple restart worked for me. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ruby version manager like RVM or rbenv to manage your ruby versions and bundler to manage your gems.

This might not answer your question about the Rails installer directly but it should allow you to install rails and ruby in a nice environment.

Install [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)

Then once that's done do a `rvm install 1.9.3` or whichever version of ruby you wish to install.

Then all you need to do is `gem install rails` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did end up going this way to install. I got a bunch of issues when trying to install rails, but was able to back up and fix them.

I still have no idea what was/is wrong with RailsInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Just login with `sudo su` in the terminal and then you can run the rails installer. I also had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these solution may work.. This is the first two thing you should try.

**1.** Restart your mac and try and again. If that fails then,

**2.** Try the following (courtesy of Treehouse):
Open Disk Utility
Choose Macintosh HD
Click Repair Disk Permissions
Restart your Mac

Adding Other people's answer here too..

**Marco S.-** Just login with sudo su in the terminal and then you can run the rails installer. I also had the same problem.

**Aaron-** I was receiving the same error message. After restarting my computer and trying the install again it worked just fine. Go figure.

**Kurtis-** I was having the exact same problem and like Aaron said a restart might fix it. It did not for me so I did one other step and changed the preference for application downloads (System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General) "Allow application downloads from:" to "Anywhere", restarted the computer and it installed just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know too much about rails installer. But you can use this great blog post by Ryan Bigg for your referral to install all the pieces yourself.

http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/mac-os-x-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

It just works.